# Ignore child element on JavaScript copy

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<li class="checked"><p>This<em>I don't need this</em></p>
<input type="checkbox"></li>
<li class="unchecked"><p>That</p>
<input type="checkbox"></li>
<button onclick="copyText()">Copy</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

And the following Javascript, that copies all elements of the class `checked` in the clipboard:

```
function copyText(){
  var outputText = "";
  var items= document.getElementsByClassName('unchecked');
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    outputText += items[i].innerText+"\n";
  }
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerText = outputText;
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(output);
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  output.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Works perfectly up until the point that it also includes the `<em>`, which, I don't want. I've tried to exclude all child elements from within `checked` but that doesn't do anything at all...
I am unable to change the class of the `<em>` as I'm working with Jekyll markdown and it's added classless (and I'd like to not use inline attributes for my input files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complement the JS with code to blank the unwanted content. This method will work as long as said content is wrapped in known tags that can be extracted by css selectors (in the given case: `em`).

Blanking is implemented by temporarily setting the Css `display` property of the unwanted elements to `none`. There was no visible effect (aka flicker) when testing.

In the example, an additional child (in boldface) has been added to the content marked as checked for demonstration purposes.

```js
function copyText(){
    var outputText = "";
    var items= document.getElementsByClassName('checked');
  
    // BEGIN - supplement to the original code
    Array.from(items).forEach ( pnode => {
        // Complement this selector to remove whatever is unwanted.
        // '*' removes all child elements.
        let nodelist_toBlank = pnode.querySelectorAll('em')
          ;
        
        // Blank the unwanted content, saving the original Css property value
        Array.from(nodelist_toBlank).forEach ( pnode_toBlank => {
            pnode_toBlank.setAttribute ( 'data-style-display', pnode_toBlank.style.display );
            pnode_toBlank.style.display = 'none';
        });
        
        // Add data from node to the string buffer. Elements with Css 'display' property set to 'none' are skipped
        outputText += pnode.innerText+"\n";
        
        // Unblank. Restore the original Css property value
        Array.from(nodelist_toBlank).forEach ( pnode_toRestore => {
            pnode_toRestore.style.display = pnode_toRestore.getAttribute ( 'data-style-display' );
            pnode_toRestore.removeAttribute ( 'data-style-display' );
        });
    });
    // END - supplement to the original code
    //
    // Original loop deleted!
    
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerText = outputText;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(output);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    output.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<li class="checked"><p>This<em>I don't need this</em><b>I want this</b></p>
<input type="checkbox"></li>
<li class="unchecked"><p>That</p>
<input type="checkbox"></li>
<button onclick="copyText()">Copy</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

***Remark***

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), *execCommand* is an obsolete feature and should no longer be used.

Comment: That works, thank you!  As for the execCommand, I didn't know that... I also have clipboard.js working on my site for a different purpose, would I be able to use that for the same purpose somehow?

Comment: I don't know clipboard.js, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

update your loop to contain an if statement :

```
var em = document.querySelector('em'); 
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (em,items[i].contains(em)){
        outputText += items[i].innerText.replace(em.innerText, "")+"\n";
        console.log(em.innerText);
    }else{
        outputText += items[i].innerText+"\n";
    }
}
```